# Menu and Back arrow are not shown in ActionBar on JellyBean

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am having a problem with the three dots menu and the back arrow in JellyBean. It's fine on newer versions. 
This is my custom theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/blue</item>
        <!-- <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item> -->

        <!-- <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/my_custom_edit_text_style</item> -->
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>
    </style>
```

I extend  `extends AppCompatActivity` and enable the "Home Back":

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This works except on JellyBean, the back button is not visible, but it's functional. 
About the menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}
```

It's there... and the same, it is not shown in JellyBean but reacts to action.
I must be missing something here, just I tried too many versions and not getting the right result. Need an extra eye. Any hints would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, totally fault. I specified the color of those elements in theme:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/blue</item>
```

Deleted this, and I can see the menu and back button back.